# Highcharts - Reverse order of negative stacked series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to reverse the order of only the negative stacked bars?

I am using Highcharts to render a stacked bar chart. When the graph render the stacks it starts from the y 0-line and render them in order which result in that the negative stacks look reversed.

**Example** (http://jsfiddle.net/moppa/6tenw/2/):

If you read the graph from bottom to top you get the following result
All series except "Grapes" get the order **Joe, Jane, John**
The "Grapes" series get the order **Jane, Joe, John**

The grapes series is not complying with the order in the legend box. Is there any way to fix this?

Code to comply with Stack Overflow guidelines:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked column chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [50, 30, 40, 70, 20]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [20, 20, 30, -20, 10]
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [30, 40, 40, -20, 50]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Good question. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: In Highcharts, for stacking we create separate stack for negative and positive values. Then, they are rendered from 0 (or rather from `threshold` option), where first series will be the outer one. Your case isn't good enough. Let's consider that example: http://jsfiddle.net/6tenw/3/ It will be always starting from Jane, because it's only positive value in a stack. How would you overcome that case?

Comment: @PawełFus - Yes, I looked at the source code and saw that negative and positive values are divided into separate stacks. What I am essentially asking for is a way to reverse the rendering order of the negative stack to make the graph comply with my legend box.
I am aware that all data series can not be fixed and that the data series you reference is a different matter. My data series are created to comply with the legend box order, but will not render correct if they stack.

Comment: Unfortunatetly, there's not such option to revers only one stack in category. Workaround will be to use separate series for negative values. Then connect negative series to 'master' one using `linkedTo`.