# Highcharts - Reverse order of stacks on negative y-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

My question is exactly as previously asked on this forum. There is no answer to the question yet. Hence reposting the question.

[Highcharts - Reverse order of negative stacked series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24135466/5052665)

I hope Highcharts team monitoring this forum will reply to this question.

The desired outcome is to stack series in the reverse order of what is currently getting rendered in the negative y-Axis (pls note the positive values are being rendered in the desired order). In other words, stack it in the order as shown in the legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still no option for reversing single stack. The solution, as mentioned in the link that you provided, is to create separate `series` for negative values and change their order. If you think this feature would be helpful, you can suggest it here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xt057jjr/

Comment: In addition to creating a separate series for negative values one has to use series method's lengendIndex property to manipulate the order of series shown in the legend.